# FIFO (FCFS) in multiprogramming

Tags: operating-system, fifo, multiprogramming

I have a question:

In which scenario FIFO (First In First Out) scheduling is possible in multiprogramming when we have only 1 processor?

Answer (score 0):

**Multiprogramming** concept is the ability of the operating system to have multiple programs in memory.

**Multiprogramming** actually mean switching between the processes or interleaving the I/O time and CPU time of processes.

So it is independent of number of processors.(i.e. Even if there is only one processor  it may be working on multiple programs.)